# Adding value to list change elements in previous list

Tags: c#, list, new-operator

I'm trying implement certain algorithm, which should use sth, what has 4 dimension.
But I have problem in adding elements to new list: when I'm adding new value to my list: temp2, the previous values in other list are changing
Can anyone show me where and what I'm doing sth wrong?

Examples:
for n=4, k=2:

when i=3,j=1
-> tab[3,1]= [{1},{2},{3}] (it should always look like this)

then when i=3,j=2 tab[3,1] is changing:
-> tab[3,1]: [{1,3},{2,3},{3}]

then when i=4,j=1
-> tab[4,1]= [{1,3},{2,3},{3},{4}]

then when i=4,j=2 tab[4,1] is changing:
-> tab[4,1]: [{1,3,4},{2,3,4},{3,4},{4}]

My code of algorithm in program

```
while (true)
{
    int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int k = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 

    List<List<int>>[,] tab = new List<List<int>>[n + 1, k + 1];

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        int j = 0;
        while (j <= i && j <= k)
        {
            tab[i, j] = new List<List<int>>();
            List<int> toAdd = new List<int>();

            if (j == 0)
            {                            
                toAdd.Clear();  //add empty
                tab[i, 0].Add(toAdd);
            }
            else if (i == j)
            {
                for (int p = 1; p <= j; p++)    
                    toAdd.Add(p);
                tab[i, i].Add(toAdd);
            }
            else
            {
                var temp = new List<List<int>>();
                var temp2 = new List<List<int>>();

                temp.AddRange(tab[i - 1, j]);         
                temp2.AddRange(tab[i - 1, j - 1]);

                foreach (var x in temp2)    //add 'i' as last element for each element of temp2
                    x.Add(i);               //here is sth wrong (bad reference?)

                temp2.Reverse();    //reverse order

                tab[i, j].AddRange(temp);
                tab[i, j].AddRange(temp2);
            }
            j++;
        }
    }
    //show tab[n,k] in console
}
```

Why I use such plain variables - I'm implementing algorithm from my classes, so I have to use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `temp2.AddRange(tab[i - 1, j - 1])` you copy the references to the lists at `[i - 1, j - 1]`. So when you modify `temp2` you modify the original list too (they are the same object).

You need to create new lists for the inner lists:

```
temp.AddRange(tab[i - 1, j].Select(l => new List<int>(l)));
temp2.AddRange(tab[i - 1, j - 1]).Select(l => new List<int>(l)));
```

Comment: It was so simple! Thank you very much! ;D
btw. the second line should be: `temp2.AddRange(tab[i - 1, j - 1].Select(l => new List<int>(l)));` - brackets are wrong